# Is it possible to setup a grid tied solar only PV system?

Tags: solar-energy

Is it possible to set up a grid tied solar only PV system? I can't have battery storage system because of budgetary reason.

I have a school which have around 5kW load and I want to add an on-grid solar PV system to it. The problem is the grid is not reliable in my area and I don't have the budget to have an off-grid solar system.

My question is would be it possible to have an on-grid solar PV system which can also work if there is a power outage in the grid. I understand that it is necessary to have an anti-islanding feature in the on-grid system, but would it be possible to disconnect the grid during the power outage and run the load on the solar PV only. Since the school doesn't need any electricity during nighttime.

I looked in to Enphase IQ microinverters with their Envoy system, but I am not sure if they can work if the grid is not present

Comment: It is possible, sort of. Some grid tie inverters have the ability to put out power on a separate circuit when the grid goes down. SMA calls this "secure power" but I think others may use different terminology.

Comment: Thanks, but  SMA SPS provides power up to 2kW and my load will definitely exceed 3kW.

Comment: Other brands may do it also and have higher power outputs. I am not sure. A backup generator may be cheaper than batteries.

Comment: In some states for safety microinverters need to shut down when there is a power grid loss. Also it's easier to make the sine wave with a reference to follow :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes and have exactly that on the system I installed on an old house that I no longer own or have access to.

The inverter injects when solar energy is present and shuts down if the grid fails.

**Can’t remember the make of the inverter** but the system is designed to match the load of the house and over the year covers the electricity used with an excess. System is sized at 3kWp. Interestingly winter output is improved as solar energy reflects off the snow to increase the panels output.

Comment: What is '3kWp'? Do you mean '3 kW peak'?

Comment: @Transistor yes, that is how many who « do » solar energy write that.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue: I need a solar system that will both inject into the grid to lower my electricity bill, and provide power during blackouts.

With grid tied inverters, this will not work, because they will shut down during a blackout. This is mandated by law : when the power company workers cut the power to work on power lines, they don't want someone's PV to inject power and electrocute them. So if it injects into the grid, it has to shut down. That makes sense : if you can even find an inverter that will inject into the grid even when there is no power, it would be a really bad idea to use it this way (ie, electrocute someone, go to jail).

There's another kind of inverters called "hybrid inverters" that can both inject into the grid and provide backup power. These have two AC connections: one main that goes to the grid, and injects power from PV panels to lower your electricity bill. They can also charge batteries with grid power. This grid connection behaves like a grid tied inverter: it will shut down in case of a blackout. The other output is separate, and provides backup power in case of blackout, using PV and batteries. I could only find one that would work without batteries, that's Fronius Primo Gen24 3.0 Plus. However the solar backup power is an option called "PV Point" that is sold separately for €1600, which doubles the price of the inverter. At this price, one may as well buy batteries instead of the PV point option.

Additionally, many of these have pretty long failover time after grid power loss. The Fronius specs 90 seconds, so it will not keep your computers up.

Note that the legal obligation of not injecting power into the grid means that, if you want a backup power supply, then you need to have two electrical circuits: one from the grid, a a separate one for backup. If you wire the whole building on backup power, then all power has to go through the inverter at all times, so you will need an inverter rated for this.

Another issue was batteries have BMS's and other electronics, which means vendor lock-in: you can only buy the battery which will be compatible with the inverter. So, batteries are way overpriced, and if the manufacturer goes under, well, tough luck for long term maintenance.

You will not be able to backup a 5kW load with 5kWp solar panels. You would need a lot more panels. If you want backup power in a blackout, then you need two electrical circuits anyway, with backup power supplied only to essential loads that must remain up. That means the requirement to do some wiring isn't that much of a drawback, since you'll have to do it anyway.

I will be installing 3 kWp solar panels. Of course this cannot power a 3kW load in case of a blackout. Depending on weather and time of day, available power will be much lower. This suits me, as it will be enough for the freezer and a heating circulator, which consume a few hundred watts total and only need to run a few hours per day.

The solution I'm going to use is quite simple:

I'm getting a basic Fronius inverter for injection to lower my electricity bill. This has all the required certifications.

I will also install a low cost solar inverter from PowMR (ie, aliexpress). This one is agnostic about batteries and they even say it will work without batteries, converting directly from PV to the backup AC output. We'll see if that works.

Then there will be a DC switch to connect the solar panels to either inverter. That could even be automated with a mains powered relay.

Note this PowMR inverter does not inject into the grid at all. Besides, I wouldn't trust something from Aliexpress to have the appropriate certifications for that, hence the Fronius. It has a mains input, that can be used to charge batteries if any, and it has a backup output. That's all.

For your use case, if you need a lot of power (5kW), perhaps a generator would be a cheaper/better option. If your blackouts are frequent but short, a generator won't use that much fuel, and it's a lot less work to install than PV. If the generator is powerful enough, you don't need to split the electrical wiring into backed-up and not backed-up loads.